# Parsing complex JSON, again

Tags: json, go, parsing, struct

I have some JSON that get via an API call and I want to now parse this using JSON, I followed an online tutorial in how to parse JSON using structs, but my actual JSON is a lot more complex than the one they used. Here is an example of the JSON I have:

```
{
    "metadata": {},
    "items": [
      {
        "metadata": {
          "name": "run7",
          "namespace": "default",
          "uid": "e218fcc4",
          "creationTimestamp": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "spec": {
          "arguments": {}
        },
        "status": {
          "phase": "Succeeded",
          "startedAt": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z",
          "finishedAt": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

and here is the strucs that I created for it:

```
type wfSpec struct{
    Arguments string
}

type wfStatus struct {
    Phase  string
    StartedAt   string
    FinishedAt    string
}

type wfMetadata struct {
    Name string
    Namespace string
    Uid string
    CreationTimestamp string
}

type Metadata []struct {
    Data string
}

type Items []struct {
    wfMetadata
    wfStatus
    wfSpec
}

type Workflow struct {
    Metadata  Metadata
    Items     Items
}
```

When I first tried to print a value using `fmt.Printf(workflows.Items.wfMetadata.Name)` I got the error `workflows.Items.Metadata undefined (type Items has no field or method Metadata)`so then I tried to just print the whole thing using `fmt.Printf(workflows)` and I got this error `cannot use workflows (type Workflow) as type string in argument to fmt.Printf`

The only data I need to parse from the JSON is the

```
"name": "run7",
"namespace": "default",
"uid": "e218fcc4",
"creationTimestamp": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"
```

Comment: `workflows.Items` is slice.  Use `workflows.Items[i].wfMetadata.Name` to access an item where `i` is the index of an item.   The first argument to fmt.Printf is a format string. Use `fmt.Print(workflows)` to print the value with the default format.

Comment: `"items":` in the JSON is not a struct but it represents an array... also you have `Items` created as `[]struct` which is a slice, so you can not access their fields directly... you need to use some indexer to access individual items and their fields.. by doing `workflows.Items[i].wfMetadata.Name`.

Comment: I would recommend to complete a basic tutorial and/or a book on Go so as to know how slices and structs work, before embarking on more complex tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off

1. The problem I expect you're having is not using the tags. To parse a JSON the names of the structs must match the names in the JSON fields. Read here [Golang Marshal](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/go1.17.6:src/encoding/json/encode.go;l=158)
2. Secondly wfMetadata has a lowecase first letter, meaning it will not be imported.
3. Thirdly, `workflow.metadata` and `workflow.items[i].spec.arguments` is set as a `{}` and not the emptystring `""`. I assume they're not supposed to be `string`. This can be avoided using the open `interface{}` if you don't know or care, or actually implementing them using the official documentations from the API you're connecting to.
4. As a note, using `[]struct` seems wrong to me. Instead define it in the usage

> Note, by using an IDE like [GoLand from jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/) they first off support converting JSON to a struct by simply pasting the JSON into a `.go` file. They might be daunting at first but do help a lot, and would do much of this for you in seconds.

Now try this instead, and understand why and how this is better and working.

```golang
type Status struct {
    Phase      string `json:"phase"`
    StartedAt  string `json:"startedAt"`
    FinishedAt string `json:"finishedAt"`
}

type ItemMetadata struct {
    Name              string `json:"name"`
    Namespace         string `json:"namespace"`
    UID               string `json:"uid"`
    CreationTimestamp string `json:"creationTimestamp"`
}

type Items struct {
    Metadata ItemMetadata `json:"metadata"`
    Status   Status       `json:"status"`
    Spec     interface{}  `json:"spec"`
}

type Workflow struct {
    Metadata interface{} `json:"metadata"`
    Items    []Items     `json:"items"`
}
```

> Working example in playground https://go.dev/play/p/d9rT4FZJsGv